# Hashids.org in Swift 3 not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, hashids

I installed the hashids.org github project (downloaded from here:  http://hashids.org/swift/ ), as I want to implement it in my project.

I need to convert 15 digit booking numbers into 5 digit alphanumeric strings, kind of like airline booking references (e.g. A5UW9).

Problem is, the hashids github project cannot run as the

```
import Hashids_Swift
```

line on the top of the HashidsTests.swift file gives an error

> No such module 'Hashids_Swift"

Any help on how to make it work from someone who has implemented it, or any advice on an alternative to achieve the conversion stated above with another method within Swift to do that?

Comment: Have you tried building the module target once?

Comment: yes and it will not build due to the above error

Comment: No, as in have you tried changing the build target to `Hashids` and building that target?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, as the only target it gives me available is "HashidsTests". Sorry, I am really new into all this

Comment: How have you imported the framework into your project? CocoaPods? Carthage? Manually?

Comment: Ok i have just installed the pod file via Cocoapods, opened the new Xcworkspace file it created, and it successfully builds and runs (although nothing happens, ie no simulator app opens). So I will now have to look at the code and  figure out how to use it for my own variables - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a .podspec, so you install it through [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/):

```
pod 'Hashids-Swift', '~> 0.3'
```